# Address Sanitizer option "-fsanitize-recover=address" is not supported

Tags: gcc, cmake, address-sanitizer

I am trying to use Address Sanitizer with gcc in my project.

So, I added the required flags in compiler as well as linker :

```
ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS(-O0 -g -Wall -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address")
```

Address Sanitizer is working after this, but it aborts my application after the first error. I want the Address Sanitizer to continue running even after reporting the error. So, I added one more flag like below (as per the link https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) :

```
ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS(-O0 -g -Wall -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-recover=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer)
```

After this I am getting the error that this recover flag is not supported :

```
Problems were encountered while collecting compiler information:
cc1plus: error: -fsanitize-recover=address is not supported
```

PS : My gcc version is gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

Answer (score 1):

I believe gcc 6 is the earliest version that supports Asan recovery mode. This mode was added in [Nov 2015](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-11/msg02644.html) whereas GCC 5 was released in April 2015.

You can [install GCC 6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746369/how-can-i-install-and-use-gcc-6-on-xenial/746480) or use Clang.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have installed Clang to use this feature.

So, to use this recovery feature, you basically need GCC 6+ or Clang 2.8+

Infact newer Clang versions have a much better option to add a txt file with all the functions you don't need to sanitize (-fsanitize-blacklist)

Comment: @mascot I think you meant Clang 3.8.

Comment: Just to be completely precise, according to [the commit info](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/21017ecb28043065575a4e269837858b5b54eb0a) you referred to earlier, the support is available from GCC 6.1.0 on.

Comment: @szotsaki Yes but there's [no GCC 6.0 release](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html) so I just called it GCC 6.